# Lost WiFi access after most recent 20.04 update

Tags: 20.04, usb, updates, realtek-wireless

Installed the update via the Software Updater this morning and after the prompted reboot I found I had lost Wifi access, as in no Wifi section available via Settings. This setup had been running just fine previous to the update. I have a TP-Link AC600 (rtl8812au) dongle.
**lsusb output**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:7663 Microdia USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0000:0538   USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1462:7c83 Micro Star International 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also have a Edimax USB WiFi adapter with a rtl8188cus chipset that I used in place of the TP-Link adapter while I dug out my ethernet cable.

[Wireless Script Info](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/PHyWJkPbqq/) I collected per the '[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)' post

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the driver for the rtl8812au chipset to no avail. I am not a power user so I am out of ideas as to how to diagnose and correct this problem

Comment: Did you install a driver for this adapter? How did you do it?

Comment: @Pilot6 I used the following commands:

    `sudo apt install build-essential`  
    `sudo apt install bc`  
    `sudo apt install linux-headers-`uname -r` `  
    `sudo apt install git`  

    `git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git`  

    `cd rtl8812au`  

    `sudo make clean`  
    `sudo make`  
    `sudo make uninstall`  
    `sudo make install`

Comment: If you install a driver this way, you'll have to install it again after each kernel upgrade. Also if you changed kernel to another major version, you may need to find another driver.

Comment: I attempted to install it again but it had no effect. I did not consciously change the kernel. I assume it was updated but I am not sure

Comment: Se were there any error messages, when you installed the driver?

Comment: @Pilot6 The only thing that looked like an error was at the end of the make process  

`Skipping BTF generation for /home/david/rtl8812au/88XXau.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Visit https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au for support/reporting issues
or check for newer versions (branches) of these drivers.`

Comment: Please don't add information to comments. [edit] your question for that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out